# Is there a Mathematica barcode reader?

Tags: image-processing

Is there a *Mathematica* barcode image reader (much like `TextRecognize`) that allows the user to enter an image of a barcode and then read it to get an output string?

Comment: 1D or 2D?  What symbology (i.e. standard)?

Answer (score 28):

Here is a bare bones, non-robust, use at your own risk, etc. [code39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) reader

```
(*get image *)
i = Binarize[Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx3JD.png", .7]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* Char encodings from Paul's article - See link bellow *)
c1 = IntegerDigits[#, 2, 9] &@{168,42,148,138,133,388,162,52,289,97,352,49,304,112,37,292,100,265,
           73,328,25,280,88,13,268,76,28,259,67,322,19,274,82,7,262,70,22,385,193,448,145,400,208};
c2 = Characters["$%*+-./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];

(*binary code for the image, drop the white flanks at the ends*)
code = Join @@ Split[Round /@ Mean /@ Transpose@ImageData@i][[2 ;; -2]];

(*get strip widths... err lengths... whatever,dropping the start/stop marks*)
lengths = Most /@ Partition[Length /@ Split@code, 10];

(*determine what is a wide and a thin strips are*)
{max, min} = {Max@#, Min@#} &@lengths;
f = Nearest[{{max} -> 1, {min} -> 0}];

(*convert from wide/thin encoding to chars*)
StringJoin @@ (Join @@@ Map[f, lengths, {2}] /. Thread[Rule[c1, c2]])
```

> "*CODE39*"

Table and encoding shamelessly stolen from [Paul Abbott's article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/Tricks9-2/Tricks9-2_2.html) on "The Mathematica Journal"

Comment: I can't get this to read other examples (eg [here](http://worldbarcodes.com/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif))

Comment: @cormullion Yep, that image hasn't white flanks. But the code works OK if you pad it. Try with  `i = ImageTake[ImagePad[Import["http://worldbarcodes.com/wp-content/uploads/39123439-code39.gif"], {{40, 40}, {0, 0}}, White], 100]` instead`

Comment: @belisarius Yep, that works. In future I'll always bring my white flanks with me... :)

Comment: This is not a barcode READER.  The question remains unanswered.

Comment: A barcode reader--just as a text reader--need not be a piece of hardware.  TextRecognize[] is purely software, for instance.  There are numerous software-only barcode readers, for instance one in MATLAB (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31727-barcode-reader).

Comment: Note:  My question asked for a barcode IMAGE reader, which is in fact SOFTWARE, as my MATLAB link proves.  Here is another link to barcode image reading software (http://zbar.sourceforge.net/).  Regardless, a barcode CREATOR is in no way a barcode READER under any circumstances.  You can read more about pattern recognition in my book "Pattern Recognition (2nd ed.)" by R. Duda, P. Hart and D. G. Stork.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This code implements a barcode reader, not a creator as you could have found if you cared to test it. Enough.

Comment: You are correct.  The code you posted looked much like (http : // www.mathematica - journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/Tricks9 - 2/Tricks9 - 2 _ 2. html) and the output appeared to be a crisp barcode (not a .jpg input image), so I mistakenly assumed yours was the same (creator) code.  My mistake.

Comment: @belisarius I tried to adapt your code to make a "barcode reader", using `ImageCapture` feeding into your `code` function via `"FrameRate" -> 5, "CaptureAction" -> (capture[#] &)`. Unfortunately my computer's camera couldn't get the barcode in focus, neither could I hold the item motionless - my arm isn't strong enough apparently. I went down to the local supermarket hoping to access their lasers but they haven't got Mathematica installed at the checkouts so was unable to test the idea any further... :)

Comment: @cormullion [You may use a small tripod to hold the camera still](http://www.google.com/imgres?client=firefox-beta&hs=Oce&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1440&bih=712&tbm=isch&tbnid=eUH1HiRr3Qx0OM:&imgrefurl=http://dreager1.com/2013/05/22/giant-condor-vs-tripod/&docid=6UGMl5ZTAxPxlM&imgurl=http://dreager1.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/war-of-the-worlds-tripod-02-1-1024x768.jpg&w=1024&h=768&ei=rNJFUs6QPNT-4AP74ICgAw&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:90,s:0,i:360&iact=rc&page=4&tbnh=177&tbnw=226&start=71&ndsp=29&tx=60&ty=59)

Comment: @cormullion I would say, too much coffee!

Answer (score 25):

Yes!... It's new in version 10. [Here is](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarcodeRecognize.html?q=BarcodeRecognize) the documentation page

The syntax is very simple:

```
BarcodeRecognize["image"]
```

It uses ZXing library (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/).

You can alse create barcode using `BarcodeImage` as these examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you know it's using the zxing library? (I missed this in the docs and I'm curious)

Comment: Secret!.. I'm a beta tester and exchanged some mails with the developer. :)

Comment: Very useful for _a lot_ of Mathematica users in the supermarket  business :)