# Accessing advanced ZXing settings for BarcodeRecognize

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Usual algorithms for detecting the presence of a QR-code in an image seem to have trouble detecting a code when it is tilted (especially at 45°). This is dependent on the resolution as well. The following shows the issue

```
DynamicModule[{img, res, img2},
Manipulate[
img = BarcodeImage[
        "This is a very long sentence \n
         meant to include lots  \n 
         and \lots and lots  \n 
         and lots and lots and lots \n 
         of bits of information to showcase the issue.", {"QR", "H"}] 
// Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> size] &;

res = (img2 = img // ImageRotate[#, \[Alpha], Background -> None] &) 
//BarcodeRecognize[#, "Data", "QR"] &;

(*Display*)
Column[{"Angle: " <> ToString[\[Alpha]*360/(2 \[Pi])], img2, 
res}], {\[Alpha], 0, 360 \[Degree] }, {size, 180, 200, 1}]
]
```

[image]

From [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38275/4597) I know that Mathematica internally use ZXing for processing QR-codes. Supposedly this library supports a "TryHarder" flag to deal with such issues by trying e.g. a rotated version of the image as well (see [here](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html)).

Can one access these settings via Mathematica's `BarcodeRecognize` as well?

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for, but you have access to all the classes in ZXing.  `decoder = JavaNew["com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Decoder"]` will create a new java object.  So you could roll your own decoding function.